# Redirect certain url from https to http

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I'm redirecting certain url from https to http in nginx. For example, from https://www.test.com/blog to http://www.test.com/blog. However, I am getting this webpage has a redirect loop error.

Ps: I'm running my web server behind HaProxy.

My nginx configuration is here:

```
location ~ ^/(blog) {
return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Add full config to post as a text (not image)

Comment: Hi Alexey, this is my config

location ~ ^/(blog) {
return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}

Comment: Your location will be evaluated regardless of http or https connection. That will cause a redirect loop because http will still redirect to http.

Comment: Hi alvits, so how can I avoid this error from occuring?

Comment: That's not **full** config